# How to retrieve attributes from LDAP in ping federate?

Tags: ldap, pingfederate

I have specified the LDAP filter option as uid=${username} to get the username. I also need to get other attributes such as organization, telephone no, email etc.. I have only one LDAP store configured in my system. I know all the configuration steps to acheive it. I am struck with the LDAP filter to get those attributes. That's where I am getting error.

for eg, in order to get organization, I should give something like o=${SOMETHING}
How to provide the filter?

Please let me know.
Thanks,
Aswini J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have already specified in the Assertion Mapping screen that you wish to "Retrieve Additional Attributes" and that you then added your existing LDAP Data Store.

The filter is simply used to locate a single user's record that you wish to return the associated attributes from. In the previous Admin screen (LDAP Directory Search) is where you specify the user attributes you wish to return. You simply specify your LDAP Base DN and then select the attributes from the drop-down list. You can find more information in the Admin Guide -

http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF73/Configuring+an+LDAP+Directory+Search#ConfiguringanLDAPDirectorySearch-2232188

After choosing the attributes, you then get to setup your LDAP Filter where something as simple as "uid=${username}" will usually suffice. It really depends on what user identifier is coming in from your IDP Adapter and how specify that lookup needs to be. If you're using the HTMLForm Adapter, then chances are your users are entering their LDAP userID values.

Comment: Thanks for your response:) PF doesn't accept anything other than uid in search filter.When I tried to give something like "(objectClass=*)=${username}, it throws me an error. But I am able to do ldapSearch using the same filter in my ldap. Thanks.

Comment: It's more than likely just your syntax. PF can accept compound & extensible search filters on this screen. However, only 1 result can be returned from the executed filter otherwise you'll get "search limit exceeded" errors.